# XQuery library under Python

Tags: python, api, xquery

Is there any existing way to run XQuery under python? (not starting to build a parser yourself in other words).

I got a ton of legacy XQuery that I want to port to our new system, or rather I want to
port the framework and not XQuery.

Therefore: Is there any library  that allows me to run XQuery under python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Sort of ...**

Looking through the [W3C implementations list for XQuery](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#implementations) there is:

1. [Python bindings for Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/)
2. [Sedna](http://modis.ispras.ru/sedna/index.html) is a free native XML database with API for [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zif.sedna).

**A few Python examples with Zorba, from [here](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/index.php/documentation/)**

```
import sys
import zorba_api

def example1(zorba):
  xquery = zorba.compileQuery("1+2")
  print xquery.printPlanAsXML()
  print xquery.execute()
  return

def example2(zorba):
  xquery = zorba.compileQuery("(1,2,3,4,5)")
  iter = xquery.iterator()
  iter.open()
  item = zorba_api.Item_createEmptyItem()
  while iter.next(item):
    print item.getStringValue()
  iter.close()
  iter.destroy()
  return

def example3(zorba):
  try:
    xquery = zorba.compileQuery("1 div 0")
    print xquery.execute()
  except RuntimeError, e:
    print e
  return
```

There may be C implementation in that list which can easily be bound to Python. Hope this helps, I was somewhat surprised to see so few implementations. Although, XQuery isn't the most desired of the XML tools I suppose.

Comment: Yeah Zobra seems to be what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: Zorba is working at UBUNTU? https://github.com/zorba-processor/zorba/issues/10

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Jython](http://www.jython.org) to run the Python code -- that gives you access to some of the XQuery processors from the Java world. For example [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Zorba 1.2 works from python. After installation you will get a python folder under zorba folder. Append it to sys.path, with zorba\bin folder also. After all manipulations import "zorba_api" will work!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like Ted and tried to use answer from vadim.
However, I had still problems to load zorba_api properly, complaining "ImportError DLL load failed" (not telling which one, using %1 as great nickname).

Finally, I got the solution:

**Environment**

- WindowsXP
- Python 2.6 installed at c:\Python26

**Installation**

- Zorba 1.2 or 1.4 installed to standard location
- **Path to Zorba bin as first item in `PATH`**
- both files from Zorba bin\python (`zorba_api.py` and `_zorba_api.pyd`) moved to `C:\Python26\LIB\site-packages`

As result, I was able to run `C:\Program Files\Zorba XQuery Processor 1.4.0\share\doc\zorba-1.4.0\python\examples\python_test.py` from any folder in my computer, even without the python line, modifying PATH

NB:

- PATH problem might be related to too long string there.
- [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896645) was of good help finding, which DLL cannot be loaded