# How to execute the xquery with some python3 library?

Tags: python-3.x, xml

The content in `books.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>       
   <book category="JAVA">
      <title lang="en">Learn Java in 24 Hours</title>
      <author>Robert</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>32.00</price>
   </book>      
   <book category="XML">
      <title lang="en">Learn XPath in 24 hours</title>
      <author>Jay Ban</author>
      <year>2010</year>
      <price>16.50</price>
   </book>       
</books>
```

I want to execute the xquery :

```
for $x in doc("books.xml")/books/book
where $x/price>30
return $x/title
```

How can wrap the xquery with some python3' library ?

Comment: Are you asking us to recommend or find a Python 3 library for XQuery? Such questions are off-topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2133648/407651